# How can I read the Windows currently playing media info in an Qt application?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

For example, when I adjust the volume using my keyboard, or simply lock my screen when playing media, I can see the media's info as well as three buttons which are "play/pause", "previous" and "next".

I want to write a desktop widget using Qt, and I want to add this control to it, allowing me to see which song is playing, change songs, see its album cover, and drag to adjust the playback progress.

I've serched "How to get the currently playing media/song info on windows" and similar questions, but found nothing useful. None of the similar questions get the WINDOWS's one using C++.

English is not my native language, and I have difficulty accessing stackoverflow. Sorry for any grammer mistake and thanks for your help.

Comment: AFAIK, Windows doesn't expose that kind of information to apps. Media players can choose to publish metadata about the media they are playing, and Windows itself will then display this metadata to users, but apps can't query the metadata.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. So I need to find every media player's sdk or some information file(s) to know what they're playing?

Comment: Doubtful that every media player has such SDKs/files. Windows has an API to let players publish metadata and react to media controls in real time. What is it that you are really trying to accomplish?